# How to configure Nginx root location proxy pass for a tomcat cluster

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx

I have a Java web application running on a tomcat(v8) cluster (2 instances) fronted by Nginx(v1).

My setup is functional when visited the url `http://localhost/MyApp`

However what I now want is to make my site accessible with just `http://localhost`

When I try with following config, page throws an error stating `Too many redirects`

```
upstream backend  {
  server web_server_1:8080;
  server web_server_2:8080;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend/MyApp;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

What would be the correct Nginx config to configure my tomcat cluster under root location?

Comment: Is your backend hit with this config or is nginx looping only on itself ? I think you have to remove /MyApp in the line `proxy_pass http://backend/MyApp;` and add it inside your upstream paths to serv1 / serv2.

Comment: It seems to loop on itself. I also tried putting MyApp into upstream URLs but it give me this error `ginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "web_server_1:8080/MyApp" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2`

Comment: The `proxy_pass` statement needs a trailing `/`.

Comment: yes, ending with a `/` gets me to my login page. However, it does not go beyond login page. I am trying to find clues from my logs.